# How to find long pressed selected item from list view for long press event using MR.Gestures in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, mr.gestures

I m using MR.Gestures for long press event on list view.
I m able to trigger long press event but not able to get listview selected long press item.

```
 <mr:ListView  x:Name="listView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding downloadedLessonsData}"
    LongPressedCommand="{Binding LongPressedCommand}"
    LongPressingCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    >
```

In viewmodel code, OnLongPressed method is getting fired on long press of listview item:

```
  protected virtual void OnLongPressed(LongPressEventArgs e)
    {
     MR.Gestures.ListView list=   (MR.Gestures.ListView) (e.Sender);
     //list.LongPressedCommandParameter; LongPressedCommandParameter is 
     //comming null, unable to get selectedItem
     Debug.WriteLine("OnLongPress");
     }
```

But I m unable to get selected long pressed item in OnLongPressed method.
Please suggest how to get selected long pressed list item in OnLongPressed method. 
I m new to xamarin forms.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your casting for selected item 
`MR.Gestures.ListView list=(MR.Gestures.ListView) (e.Sender);`

is wrong. you have to cast it to model if each selected item is a collection.

`protected virtual void OnLongPressed(LongPressEventArgs e)
    {
     var selectedItem=(Model name be be given)e.Sender;
     ' //now you will get the selected model in selectedItem'
     }`

you have to cast it to datatype if each selected item is a single value(eg: string).

`protected virtual void OnLongPressed(LongPressEventArgs e)
    {
     var selectedItem=(string)e.Sender;
     ' //now you will get the selected string in selectedItem'
     }`

Comment: Sender value is coming as {MR.Gestures.ListView}. Its not coming as model type.

Comment: Ideally this should work,might be you have done something wrong. Please go through this sample, might be helpful for you https://github.com/MichaelRumpler/GestureSample/blob/master/GestureSample/GestureSample/Views/MainPage.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `listView.SelectedItem` (as the selected item will be set when you touch a cell) or you handle `LongPress` on each `Cell`. Then you get the pressed `Cell` in the `sender`.

In your code the signature of the `OnLongPressed` method is wrong, but if it gets executed, then this is just a copy&paste error.

Comment: I m able to execute OnLongPressed. Can you please suggest how i can use listView.SelectedItem with mr.listview so hat i can get item in onLongPress method. I m very new to xamarin form.  please suggest Thanks.

Comment: You wrote <mr:ListView  x:Name="listView" in your xaml. This creates a member in your class with the name "listView". And that listView has a property SelectedItem https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.SelectedItem/. The SelectedItem holds the selected item you asked for.